# Killing vectors for a boundary condition?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, boundary-conditions

So here's something I was wondering about. Let's say I have to have boundary conditions in flrw metric which does not leave the universe isotropic and homogeneous. This would go against observations. Thus the boundary condition too must respect this. But I know how to apply killing vectors on tensors not boundary conditions. How does one then proceed to find all possible boundary conditions which leave preserve isotropy and homogeneity?

Comment: Killing vectors for fun and profit?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Sorry. I didn't get you

Comment: just a lame joke, as in killing vectors with a shotgun. "killing" as the verb, not the noun.

Comment: This sounds like the gauge-fixing approach in asymptotic symmetries (like [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.08367)), except that you want to find the boundary conditions in this case

Comment: @KP99 also if you had any thoughts on this. It would be helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731228/can-one-visualise-this-in-general-relativity

Comment: I do not have a MSE account, so I'm commenting here: I think your proposition is wrong, E.g. : Consider FRW geometry with $u^{\alpha}=(1,0,0,0)$ (in +,-,-,- conv). Then the Jacobi-equation yields $\partial_t\eta^{\alpha}=0$. Likewise, for translational vectors ($v_x,v_y,v_z$), we get $\partial_i\eta^{\alpha}=0$. Then $\eta^{\alpha}=0$ which leads to a contradiction. Anyway, notice that $v_i$'s are not proportional to $u_i$

Comment: @KP99 the proportionality is only for the spatial components.

Comment: yeah but even component wise its not same, no?

Comment: How did you go to $\eta^\alpha = 0$? Shouldn't it be $\eta^\alpha =$ constant?

Comment: Actually it should be a function of time perhaps?